# jump to specific time in videojs using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, video.js, ecmascript-next

I am trying to implement feature to jump 15 seconds forward or backward in video.

I am facing hard time to set the update and set the current time.

```
const videoNode = useRef(null);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(null);

  const handleTimeJump = (type) => {
    const player = videojs(videoNode.current);
    console.log(player)
    if (player) {
      type === 'inc' && setCurrentTime(player.currentTime() + 15);
      player.currentTime() > 15 ? setCurrentTime(player.currentTime() - 15) : setCurrentTime(0)
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = videojs(
      videoNode.current,
      videoJsOptions,
      function onPlayerReady() {
        console.log('onPlayerReady');
        player.on('timeupdate', () => {
          setCurrentTime(player.currentTime());
        });
      },
    );
    if (!videoJsOptions.sources[0].src) {
      console.log('no source found');
    }
    return () => {
      if (player) {
        player.dispose();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = videojs(videoNode.current)
    player.currentTime(currentTime)
}, [currentTime])
```

handleTimeJump is called after clicking a button.

```
onClick={() => handleTimeJump('inc')}
```

Comment: What's actually happening when you click? What exactly not working?

Answer (score 0):

Look I haven't tested if it works but looks like it should be [`player.setCurrentTime(currentTime)`](https://docs.videojs.com/html5#setCurrentTime) instead of `player.currentTime(currentTime)`

If that works then they should have thrown an error when calling `currentTime` with an argument because [it is not supposed to take an argument](https://docs.videojs.com/html5#currentTime) <sub><sup>(*cough* or you could use a statically typed language *cough*)</sup></sub>

Also the `currentTime` state is already in the videojs-land there's no need to create another in React-land and keep them in sync.  You're dispatching a react update EVERY SECOND. Here's a higly recommended and unsolicited refactor (keeping diff as less as possible):

```
const videoNode = useRef(null);
const playerRef = useRef(null);
const player = playerRef.current;

const handleTimeJump = (type) => {
  if (player) {
    type === 'inc' && player.setCurrentTime(player.currentTime() + 15);
    player.currentTime() > 15 ? player.setCurrentTime(player.currentTime() - 15) : player.setCurrentTime(0)
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  playerRef.current = videojs(
    videoNode.current,
    videoJsOptions
  );
  if (!videoJsOptions.sources[0].src) {
    console.log('no source found');
  }
  return () => {
    if (player) {
      player.dispose();
    }
  };
}, []);
```